# How to use two types different forms of induction to prove stamp problem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

For this problem I have to prove using two different types of induction to show that using only 3 cent stamps and 5 cent stamps, any postage amount 8 cents or greater can be formed. Using the two styles of induction. I'm not sure if what I have is correct could someone please help me out?

I think I've done the one with the strong induction, which has multiple base cases before the induction step. That is if it's correct.

Ex: Base cases: $$P(8) = 8 = 3 +5,\\
                P(9) = 9 = 3*3 + 5(0),\\
                P(10) = 10 = 3(0) + 5(2)$$

Induction step: assume $n$ is greater than $10$, then $n-3$ greater than or equal to $8$ is true. Let $a'$ and $b'$ such that $n-3 = 3a' + 5b'$

$$n = 3+ (n-3)\\
  = 3 + 3a' + 5b\\
  = 3(a' + 1) +5b'$$

I'm not sure if this is correct or not.

Since there isn't a LHS or RHS how would I prove this using another form of induction?

Comment: Your proof is excellent. Actually, this is just induction with steps of size $3$ (thus needing $3$ base cases). Normally, strong induction means induction where the statement for $n=k+1$ is derived from all the statements $n=1$, $n=2$, $\ldots$, $n=k$ (the "strong" inductive hypothesis).

Comment: @user133281 Ok thank you. How would I solve this using another form of induction?